# Prophet model in scikit-hts package is not working

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, forecasting

I'm exploring hierarchal forecasting for time series in python and came across [scikit-hts](https://scikit-hts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library. I installed the package using `pip install scikit-hts`. I followed the steps mentioned in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-hierarchical-time-series-forecasting-part-ii-e73dfd3de86b) tutorial. I created the hierarchal tree and came to the modelling part. I want to predict bottom level forecast using Facebook prophet algorithm. I ran the following code

```
clf = hts.HTSRegressor(model='prophet', revision_method='AHP', n_jobs=0)
model = clf.fit(hierarchy_train, hierarchy)
```

This has thrown the warning message,

```
Fitting models:   0%|          | 0/46 [00:00<?, ?it/s]prophet model requires fbprophet to 
work. Exiting.Install it with: pip install scikit-hts[prophet]
Fitting models:   0%|          | 0/46 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

and this error message,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

I tried to install every additional package from [here](https://scikit-hts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). But it is throwing the following error message for every package (here only shown for arima model)

```
zsh: no matches found: scikit-hts[arima]
```

Can someone please explain why it is happening? Is it because that the packages are discontinued or is there a issue in my installation process?

Edit:

1. I have updated my version of scikit-hts but still `pip install scikit-hts[x]` (where `x=all/geo/arima/prophet`) didn't work
2. I ran my code in the jupyter notebook. All models worked except for prophet. Here is the code.

   ```
   clf = hts.HTSRegressor(model='x', revision_method='OLS', n_jobs=20)
   model = clf.fit(hierarchy_train, hierarchy)
   ```

This code ran for x = `auto_arima`, `holt_winters`, `sarimax` but not for `prophet`
I got the following error when I tried `prophet`

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Why is the model not running for `prophet`?

- I don't know if it is relevant or not but I have installed statsmodels packages for arima and other smoothening models. I have installed fb-prophet on my system but I didn't import in my notebook. I have only done `import hts`

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with the same parameters. It worked without any errors. May be they've fixed this issue in the later versions of 0.5.4. Try checking the same once after upgrading your package. If you haven't done that so far.

Comment: I have updated to latest version of scikit-hts, v 0.5.6. When I tried to install additional dependencies like `pip install scikit-hts[prophet]`, `pip install scikit-hts[all]` etc. All of them are throwing the same error `no matches found: scikit-hts[all]`. Could you tell me how did you install additional dependencies?

Comment: I've installed additional dependencies using `pip install scikit-hts[all]`, It worked as well. So, Try uninstalling everything related to scikit-hts and then re-install again with `pip install scikit-hts`, `pip install scikit-hts[all]` or Try the same commands in a new environment.

Comment: Hi. I have added some edits. Could you please check

Comment: You don't have import prophet though, `import hts` is enough. Have you used  `pip install prophet` or `pip install fbprophet`.

Comment: Installed fb-prophet using `pip install fbprophet`

Comment: As of v1.0, the package name on PyPI is `prophet`; prior to v1.0 it was `fbprophet`. `scikit-hts` requires prophet to be installed. so, Could you please try installing prophet with `pip install prophet`

Comment: Hi. Uninstalled current versions of `pystan` and `fbprophet`. reinstalled them again. Current version of `prophet` is `1.0 ` which is latest one. version of `pystan` I'm using is `2.19.1.1 ` which is compatible with `prophet`. Still getting the same error for prophet as mentioned

Comment: Then, I think It's not the issue with the package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232792/discussion-between-sky-ap-and-monkeydluffy).

Comment: Heya, author of scikit-hts here. Has this been resolved?

Comment: Hey @CarloMazzaferro, I'm not facing any issues but the other user is. I think you're the right person to address his issue.

Comment: Hey @MonkeyDLuffy did it help to run  pip install 'scikit-hts[all]', using pip install by enclosing the package name in '' , this avoids zsh misinterpreting the package name.

Comment: Did anybody managed to run the prophet model in hts? Installing prophet via pip install prophet or pip install scikit-hts[propet] did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter, you need to escape the brackets like this to install the dependencies

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install scikit-hts\[prophet\]
```